# Why does Laravel call POST route on page reload?

Tags: php, html, laravel, post, get

I don't understand while Laravel continually calls the "post" on page reload.

This is the relevant part of my Route file:

```
Route::get('tag', [
'middleware' => 'auth',
'uses' => 'TaggerController@index'
]);

Route::post('tag', [
'middleware' => 'auth',
'uses' => 'TaggerController@store'
]);
```

It calls TaggerController@store on page reload, not TaggerController@index, which is what I was expecting. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you saying that even when you navigate to index, and hit refresh, it loads Store?  If, however, you submit a post request and then hit refresh, the correct behavior is to resubmit the post request

Answer (score 0):

Because you're reloading a `post` request.

If you write the URL in the direction bar and hit "go", it will send a `get`request. But if you tried a `post` (by sending a form, for example) and you reload the page by clicking in the browser `reload` button, or by pressing Ctrl+R, it will try the post again (along with all the previous post parameters), and then the routing rule for the post action is called.

Comment: How do you redirect it to a get on refresh? Is this possible?

Comment: I'm also keen to know the answer to @fungusanthrax's question.